# Given: $\Omega(n)= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{i}-i}{\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i}}-i}$, then compute sum of digits of $\Omega(2022)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given: $ \Omega(n)= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{i}-i}{\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i}}-i}$, then compute sum of digits of $\Omega(2022)$.

---

I tried to convert it into a telescopic series. I used some algebraic manipulation and got that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{i}-i}{\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i}}-i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(\sqrt{i}-1)(i+\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i}})}{i \sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i}+1}$ which doesn't look useful to me at all. I have just been trying to split them so that I can create any telescopic series but it's not working out.

Comment: Visibly you have  attempted to "rationalize the denominator" in order to get rid of square roots in the denominator. But you have stopped after the first step. There is a second rationalization to attempt... Besides, if they are telling "sum of digits", isn't it implicitly saying that the result is an integer ? Moreover, please give the origin of the exercice.

Comment: The sum is not a whole number, so the sum of digits is not a clear question.

Comment: I think the question is $  
\Omega(2022)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2022} \left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{i}-i}{\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i}}-i}\right\rfloor$ which is equal to 2023 so then you can ask the sum of the digits.

Comment: @Henry While I'm not sure if there was a floor function to be included, how did you get the above expression to be equal to 2023? What are the steps that you have taken?

Comment: So, y=1 is a horizontal asymptote for decreasing function $a_i=\frac{\sqrt{i}-i}{\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i}}-i}$ and $a_1=0$ and $\left\lfloor a_2\right\rfloor=3$ and $\left\lfloor a_i\right\rfloor=1$ for i>2. So, now you can make the conclusion.